# My python application creates an html file but when I freeze it with pyinstaller it does not create anything, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, fwrite

I've made a program that simply creates an HTML file in the location where the Python script is executed.

The problem is that after having freeze my application with PyInstaller, the executable no longer creates the HTML file as intended but does nothing. (It only makes the print statement of my program appear.)

Is there a way to get around this?

*I used the `open("x.html","w+")` function to create the HTML file.

The code that creates the HTML looks like this:

```
def create_html():
    f = open("x.html", "w+")
    f.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n")
    f.close()
```

I think what would fix the problem is to create the html file outside the working directory. However I have no idea how to do that.

After looking around I've found that my program does indeed work but creates the html file in the home directory on my mac. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Are you building in onefile mode or in onedir mode?

Comment: I'm building in onefile mode.

Comment: Try without that option and with `--onedir` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
f = open ("x.html", "wb")
```

or if you need to add at the end of the file you can use

```
f = open ("x.html", "a")
```

although you can also use py2exe to generate an executable.

Comment: What does "wb" does which is different the "w+"? I'm on mac so I can't use py2exe unfortunately.

Comment: @Nassims No,it is shouldn't be ``wb``.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code is `open("x.html", "w+")` instead of `open("/x.html", "w+")`?

Try to use 
`open("./x.html", "w+")` and try again.
You should learn about absolute path and relative path.

> After looking around I've found that my program does indeed work but creates the html file in the home directory on my mac.

Is your program install in home directory?

Comment: Using pyinstaller it creates a unix executable that I've put on my desktop and then I launched the program there. It created the html file in my home directory despite the program being on my desktop.

Comment: I did the thing you suggest but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I tried using this Users/./Desktop/queue.html but it didn't work.

Comment: @Nassims If you run this code in your IDE(without using pyinstaller),does it also create a ``html`` file in root directory?